# Error in access PeripheralManager class in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-things

Trying to get the PeripheralManager class in Xamarin application and got the following error.

> Target API : 29
>
> Error logs:
>
> Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace --- java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Stub!     at
>   com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManager.getInstance(PeripheralManager.java:21)
>     at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.n_onClick(Native Method)    at
>   crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.onClick(ButtonRenderer.java:95)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774)   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

**Note:**
1. Created a native android library project with AdnroidThings API (PerpheralManager) and generated android library file
2. Added this file in Xamarin project to access the PerpheralManager class

Comment: I would suggest you show us the code where this happens or else we would just be speculating

Comment: Thanks @FreakyAli.

Note: 
1. Created a native android library project with AdnroidThings API (target version 29)(PerpheralManager) and generated android library file 
2. Added this .jar or .aar file in Xamarin project to access the PerpheralManager class

Comment: Which hardware do you use?

Comment: It is a GPS receiver with serial port communication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Xamarin's compilation system, but you should make sure that your Android Manifest correctly includes the `uses-library` tag to pull in the library logic.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```